# Rotating Twitter Bootstrap4 Navbar Menu/Submenu Caret

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, submenu

Looking for some help from the experts here! I managed to rotate the original drop down caret on BS4. However, I'm having trouble rotating the **submenu** caret, would anyone please take a look and criticize what I might be doing wrong? I'm hoping to avoid utilizing FontAwesome for this, and keeping it to CSS and Bootstrap4 if possible.

Thank you and much appreciated!

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom py-1" style="background-color:#0082bb;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" base target="parent">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler update-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerToggle" aria-controls="navbarTogglerToggle" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

  </button>
  <div class="collapse show navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerToggle">

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" base target="parent">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Resources
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" base target="parent">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" base target="parent">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" base target="parent">Submenu action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" base target="parent">Another submenu action</a></li>
```

```
.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}


.dropdown-toggle:after {
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this, we look for a click on `.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-toggle` and add/remove a class which changes the direction of the caret from left to down and back. Complete code below:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
  });

  return false;
});

/* for TOP LEVEL MENU */
$('.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('caretDown')) {
    $(this).removeClass('caretDown');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('caretDown');
  }
});

/* for SUB MENUS */
$('.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('caretDown')) {
    $(this).removeClass('caretDown');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('caretDown');
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}

#navbarDropdownMenuLink::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

a.caretDown::after {
  transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a>
              </li>


              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**UPDATE**: the toggle for the top navigation link caret was not done previously, corrected after pointer by the questioner

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this! However, what happens in this one, is the original drop down is now disabled. It seems the class is now attributed only to the submenu, rather than two separate ones. One for the Original drop down caret, and one for the Submenu Caret.

Thank you again!

Comment: Hi @NewCodeJunkie, thanks for pointing that out, i completely missed it... the code is updated to account for the very top caret also.

Comment: Wow thank you! That captures my ask, though I do have one question if this is a possibility. The previous method i had utilized the on aria-expanded:true trigger to change the caret back to the original position when the active menu isn't open. Is this still possible to have carets coded to revert back to original position when the selected menu is no longer active?


i have also marked your answer as correct. Much appreciated!